# NVIDIA Jetson TX2: Usb 2-3-port2: Cannot enable: Maybe the USB cable is bad?

Tags: usb, nvidia-jetson

I am using NVIDIA Jetson TX2 and I need to connect a camera to the usb port in the title. Once I connect the device to the usb port for the first time (no matter if before or after booting), I get the following error:

```
[ 383.132664] usb 2-3.4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using tegra-xusb
[ 383.153326] usb 2-3.4: New USB device found, idVendor=8086, idProduct=0b3a
[ 383.153367] usb 2-3.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 383.153374] usb 2-3.4: Product: Intel(R) RealSense™ Depth Camera 435i
[ 383.153379] usb 2-3.4: Manufacturer: Intel(R) RealSense™ Depth Camera 435i
[ 383.153385] usb 2-3.4: SerialNumber: 045323051018
[ 387.232712] usb 2-3-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 391.308686] usb 2-3-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 395.380654] usb 2-3-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 399.452674] usb 2-3-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 403.524704] usb 2-3-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 407.596712] usb 2-3-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 411.668625] usb 2-3-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
```

Not only does this compromise the camera, but also all the other usb devices (e.g. the mouse and the keyboard are no longer able to work properly)
If i unplug the camera and I plug it in again, everything seems to be working:

```
[ 411.668970] usb 2-3.4: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 415.884647] usb 2-3-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 419.956664] usb 2-3-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 420.180536] usb 2-3.4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using tegra-xusb
[ 420.201212] usb 2-3.4: New USB device found, idVendor=8086, idProduct=0b3a
[ 420.201226] usb 2-3.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 420.201232] usb 2-3.4: Product: Intel(R) RealSense™ Depth Camera 435i
[ 420.201238] usb 2-3.4: Manufacturer: Intel(R) RealSense™ Depth Camera 435i
[ 420.201243] usb 2-3.4: SerialNumber: 045323051018
[ 420.262547] uvcvideo: Unknown video format 00000050-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71
[ 420.262585] uvcvideo: Unknown video format 00000032-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71
[ 420.263360] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.50 device Intel(R) RealSense™ Depth Camera 435i (8086:0b3a)
[ 420.276804] uvcvideo: Unable to create debugfs 2-4 directory.
[ 420.277447] uvcvideo 2-3.4:1.0: Entity type for entity Intel(R) RealSense™ Depth Ca was not initialized!
[ 420.277659] uvcvideo 2-3.4:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[ 420.277800] uvcvideo 2-3.4:1.0: Entity type for entity Intel(R) RealSense™ Depth Ca was not initialized!
[ 420.277963] uvcvideo 2-3.4:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[ 420.278642] input: Intel(R) RealSense™ Depth Ca as /devices/3610000.xhci/usb2/2-3/2-3.4/2-3.4:1.0/input/input9
[ 420.278924] uvcvideo: Unknown video format 36315752-1a66-a242-9065-d01814a8ef8a
[ 420.278940] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.50 device Intel(R) RealSense™ Depth Camera 435i (8086:0b3a)
[ 420.282469] uvcvideo: Unable to create debugfs 2-4 directory.
[ 420.284465] uvcvideo 2-3.4:1.3: Entity type for entity Processing 7 was not initialized!
[ 420.284649] uvcvideo 2-3.4:1.3: Entity type for entity Extension 8 was not initialized!
[ 420.284804] uvcvideo 2-3.4:1.3: Entity type for entity Camera 6 was not initialized!
[ 420.285465] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[ 420.285471] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[ 426.256314] usb 2-3.4: usb_suspend_both: status 0
[ 426.304304] usb 2-3: usb_suspend_both: status 0
[ 426.304472] usb usb2: usb_suspend_both: status 0
```

Plus, if I connect the device to another usb port everything works fine since the very first tentative. However, this is not a solution, since I need to connect the camera to that specific usb port for practical reasons. Did anyone run into this issue? Does anyone know how to help me?

Answer (score 0):

I frequently run into usb issues when using the dji manifold 2 with its usb ports (as well as with the usb extension hub)

The trick i used is simply to plug everything in first, before turning the device on. It seemed to have worked for me. You may want to try that too. While this is not a permanent fix, I hope it will work for you